# starter won't engage and checked the flex plate its good its new starter

Tags: starting, dodge, starter

1996 v6 magnum 3.19 engine new starter check flex plate and its good I've put new ignition switch in it couple times and I think my universal joint is bad it's missing a clip or 2 also have tried another starter still just making spinning sound tried rocking my truck back and forth  n the universal joint in the back barely moves but one in front moves alot I don't know what could be keeping it from cranking but please help I afraid I'm going to loose it if don't figure it out soon and it'd first vehicle I've had in 20yr really need it for work

Comment: Does it have automatic or manual transmission?

Comment: The ring gear on the flex plate is good and the starter just spins without cranking? Then it's the wrong starter for this vehicle. Find the right starter and it will work.

Comment: it's the same starter that was on it before I don't know what the sound was when I pulled over but it was loud and it was coming from below my seat I checked the u joint and it is missing a couple clips would that be the problem or would I need shims for a new starter

Comment: Your rear differential has more gear lash due to wear than the front, so rear U joint will move less when rocking the drive train via a rear wheel. Some U joints have no clips, they have molded retainers. If clips are missing on a U joint, this has no effect on a starter. I don't know if your starter needs shims, but a little shim will not make the difference between engaging the ring gear and missing it entirely. You have the wrong starter or the Bendix mechanism is bad. Suggest you remove the starter and connect it to jumper cables to see if the pinion gear extends out or not when it spins.

Comment: And here is more information about U joints with molded plastic retainers but no clips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Xv5AuuoieY

Comment: what could be the noise that I heard when I pulled it over and turned it off  it is also a 4×4 and my boss tried to fix my fuse box and it is torn apart now could this be a reason for it not working my gear column wire broke also

Comment: it's a automatic 4×4

Comment: also have fuse box problems